# He is coming on a bicycle

Tags: grammaticality, idiomatic-language

> He is coming on a bicycle.

Why is this wrong?

Personally, I would prefer "by bike", as it just sounds more natural to me. But I fail to see any problem with the sentence.

Comment: It depends on the context. I can certainly think of situations where there is nothing wrong with that sentence. However, it is _not_ the _idiomatic_ way to express that he will be travelling by bike. (Context is key - I can even think of contexts where the sentence has nothing to do with travel at all)

Comment: Well if you don't like it, don't use it. Simple as that!

Comment: Two people have posted answers, but the question is too ambiguous to really be answerable.  Why do you (or somebody) think it's wrong, and what aspect is allegedly wrong?

Answer (score 1):

> He is coming **by** bicycle.

Use *by* because it is a means of transportation from point A to point B.

> He is **riding on** a bicycle.

is OK because *on* indicates your position related to the bicycle.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think

> He is coming **on a** bicycle.

is incorrect?  It has the same meaning as

> He is coming **by** bicycle.

usually meaning

> He is **riding** a bicycle here.

Other examples are

> He is coming on a plane.
>   He is coming on a train.
>   He is coming in a car.

are all correct.